# Showing that there is an isomorphism on $\phi(x)=x^{1/3}$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

If you have a map from $\left \langle \mathbb{R},*  \right \rangle$ to $\left \langle \mathbb{R},*  \right \rangle$, defined by  $\phi (x)=x^{1/3} $ for all x ∈ $\mathbb{Q}$, how can you show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism of $\left \langle \mathbb{R},*  \right \rangle$ with itself?

My idea is to show one to one, onto, homomorphism.

Homomorprihsm seems simple:

$\phi (x*y)=\phi (x*y)^{^{1/3}}=x^{1/3}*y^{1/3}=\phi (x)*\phi(y)$

Onto seems tricker:

$\phi\sqrt[1/3]{q}=\sqrt[1/3]{q}^{1/3}=q$

and my idea for one to one is the same:

$x_{1},x_{2}$ ∈ $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\phi(x_{1})=\phi(x_{2})$

= $(x_{1})^{1/3}=(x_{2})^{1/3}=\sqrt[1/3]{x_{1}^{1/3}}=\sqrt[1/3]{x_{2}^{1/3}}=x1=x2$

That seems to be the only approach I can see for one to one.

How is this approach all in all? Or could I do a better job some place?

Comment: How is $\phi$ defined why $x\not\in\mathbb Q$?

Comment: $\left \langle \mathbb{R},*  \right \rangle$ is not a group. We need to exclude $0$.

Comment: Additionally, if you dislike roots, you can look at the map $\varphi(x) = x^3$ instead.  Show that it's an isomorphism, then then show that $\phi\circ\varphi(x) = x$, so it's the inverse of $\phi$.  It then follows immediately that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I think it makes sense as a monoid morphism.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is an isomorphism. And your "onto" doesn't make sense. To cancel the $\frac13$ you need you have a cube. This is mapping $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q$ is a proper subset of $\Bbb R$. This may work when mapping $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb Q$ but I am not sure that it works in this situation. I think you need $\phi$ defined so that it encompasses all of $\Bbb R$.